# Why are there two ways of indicating error in Elixir?

Tags: error-handling, elixir

Some Elixir functions have 2 variants for indicating error

1. Return a tuple e.g. `File.open` which returns something like `{:ok, io_device}` or `{:error, posix}`
2. Raise exception e.g. `File.open!`

My questions are:

1. What's the intention of having two ways?
2. Is one preferred over the other (like best practices)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of handling errors, because there are two types of errors:

- the expected errors - like user providing bad data, etc. In that case you use the tuple-style return values to handle the error. This also forces the caller to consider the error case and handle it properly.
- the truly unexpected exceptions - like a configuration file suddenly disappearing, that can't be recovered from and that there's not much to do beside crashing. In that case you raise an exception.

Because of those two ways, you extremely rarely find yourself in need of rescuing exceptions - where in other languages you would rescue an exception, in Elixir you avoid raising it in the first place, and rather return an ok/error tuple instead.

I'd say the tuple-style is superior, as it gives control to the caller - the caller can decide what to do with the error by either pattern matching on the return value in a `case` expression and handling both possibilities, or, ignoring the erroneous one, pattern matching directly on the `ok` tuple. The second one will convert the return value to a `MatchError` exception, should the unexpected error occur. You can see how the first style can be easily converted to the second one. That said many libraries provide "bang" functions that raise the error for ease of use and ability to provide better error messages than a plain `MatchError` does allow.

While the `{:ok, value}` is often paired with `{:error, reason}`, it's merely a convention. There are many APIs that return only `:error` without a reason, where the reason is obvious, there are also some that return something different in the successful case. The rule here is to provide an easy pattern match that is not order dependent. Let's see some examples:

```
{value, rest} | :error
```

That's a good choice, since the cases are easily distinguishable - this style is used, for example by `Integer.parse/2`. If the success condition has two return values and there's only one reason for failure, this style is recommended.

```
string | :error
```

This doesn't seem like a good idea, you'd either need to have a guard in the pattern match or be careful to match the `:error` atom first. Instead, one would wrap the success value in a `{:ok, string}` tuple for ease of use.